# Multiple JOIN, with one table needed two times

Tags: sql, laravel

i am trying to make up this situation in my app: there are users who can select the languages they speak (such as english, spanish, japanese and so on) and users who can confirm the languages selected by others users (like in LinkedIn, where you can confirm the skill of another person).

I have 4 tables in a DBRM: Users, Languages, Users_Language and Users_Confirmations.
The bodies:

```
Users
id name lastname ...

Languages
id name

Users_Languages
user_id language_id

Users_Confirmations
user_id language_id other_id   ------> here other_id refers to Users table, like user_id. They both refer to Users table, since an user can confirm another user
```

For example:
John Smith speaks English, Spanish and Danish.
Luke Red and Jennifer Brown confirmed English on John Smith.

Now, I want to get all Users who, for example, have confirmed the user with id "4", and show them in a HTML list. And I would want to get it with both PURE SQL and Laravel (Eloquent or Query Builder).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're repeating data in `users_confirmations`; couldn't you just have `users_languages_id` and `confirmer_id` (`id` of the `user` that is confirming it). Pivot tables can have primary keys, like `id`, so you could like that to `users_languages_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to change your table attributes to avoid repetition, use just
Users_Languages_ID as a foreign key to refer to the Users_Langages table

```
-- Users_Confirmations
confirmation_id  user_language_id
```

You can just use Users_Confirmations, and for each confirmation added, you will insert a row that contains user_language_id

Returning to the question(to get users who confirmed the user with id "4")

```
SELECT Users.name, Users.lastname, Languages.name 
FROM Users_Confirmations
JOIN Users_Languages ON Users_Languages.id = Users_Confirmations.user_language_id
JOIN Languages ON Languages.id = Users_Languages.language_id
JOIN Users ON Users.id = Users_Languages.user_id 
WHERE Users_Languages.user_id = 4
```